# Некорректно выводятся посты на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Почему выводятся некорректно посты? the_title() возвращает заголовок не данного поста, а страницы, на которой выводятся данные посты. Как я понял, что-то не так с the_post(); Как исправить?

```
<?php get_header();?>
        <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ): ?>
                <?php the_post();?>
                <div class="mini-card">
                    <a class="mini-card__link" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                                <p class="mini-card__name"><?php the_title();?></p>
                    </a>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Попробуйте выше цикла написать: wp_reset_postdata();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуй так

```
$args = array(
'category_name=слаг_категории'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    the_title();
}
} else {
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Слаг категории, это слаг страницы?

Comment: Да, работает! Спасибо! Действительно дело в том, что не на главной вывожу посты

Comment: слаг рубрики с которой подтянуть посты

Comment: @Igor дело не в этом, а в том, что вы рушите основной цикл wp. В данном ответе вам предлагается делать свой цикл через WP_Query, что правильно, и избавляет вас от проблемы.

Comment: Выкинул из ответа "У страниц нету постов" как очевидное непонимание. Страницы - те же посты с post_type = page. А код правильный, потому что он не портит основной цикл WP

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `the_title();` использовать `echo get_the_title($post->ID)`
А вобще, не должно сбоить. Может ты выводишь внутри [цикла wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress)? Тогда надо делать это через новый объект `WP_Query`.

Comment: echo get_the_title($post->ID) торжественно равно the_title(); Посмотрите код в ядре. А вот предположение насчёт "внутри цикла" - правильное, плюсую

Comment: Посмотрите код the_title() в wp-includes/post-template.php и увидите, что переопределить ее невозможно. Она не заключена в `if ( function_exists( 'the_title' ) ) {}. При попытке добавления функции с именем the_title() в functions.php получите 500.